# Method 'fetch_assoc' not found in array - Error how do i fix it?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to retrieve information from a database and put it into a table in PHP and HTML however, i've encountered a problem where it says ive got an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   F:\Client Server\Website\campsites.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown

when I check the line that the error is in it says :

> Method 'fetch_assoc' not found in array

How can I fix this?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $_SESSION['search'] = $search;

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM campsites ='$search'";
    $result = $campDataSet->fetchAllCamps($sqlQuery);

    if($result > 0){

        echo'<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead id="table1Head">
                    <tr><td>campID</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>Postcode</td>
                        <td>Country</td>
                        <td>Latitude</td>
                        <td>Longitude</td>
                        <td>email</td>
                        <td>Phone<td></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

              </div>';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_campsite']. '</td> <td>' . $row['campsite_name'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['address'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['postcode']. '</td> <td>' . $row['country']. '</td> <td>' . $row['lattitude']. '</td> <td>' . $row['longitude']. '</td> <td>' . $row['email']. '</td> <td>' . $row['phone_number']. '</td> </td>';
        }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    } else {
        print " 0 results";
    }
}
```

EDIT :

```
var_dump($result);

array(1) { [0]=> object(DBdata)#6 (11) { ["db"]=> NULL ["conn"]=> object(PDO)#7 (0) { } 
    ["id_campsite"]=> string(1) "1" ["campsite_name"]=> string(13) "lake district" ["address"]=> string(32) "lake distrcit greater manchester"  
    ["postcode"]=> string(7) "m21 8fx" ["country"]=> string(7) "England" ["lattitude"]=> string(13) "1 0800 243230" ["longitude"]=> string(12) "120312310978" 
     ["email"]=> string(14) "lake@gmail.com" ["phone_number"]=> string(12) "059874327823" } }
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for this error is that `$campDataSet->fetchAllCamps($sqlQuery)` returns an array. In this case your code should look like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $_SESSION['search'] = $search;

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM campsites ='$search'";
    $result = $campDataSet->fetchAllCamps($sqlQuery);

    if (count($result) > 0) {
        echo'<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead id="table1Head">
                    <tr><td>campID</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>Postcode</td>
                        <td>Country</td>
                        <td>Latitude</td>
                        <td>Longitude</td>
                        <td>email</td>
                        <td>Phone<td></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

            </div>';
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_campsite']. '</td> <td>' . $row['campsite_name'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['address'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['postcode']. '</td> <td>' . $row['country']. '</td> <td>' . $row['lattitude']. '</td> <td>' . $row['longitude']. '</td> <td>' . $row['email']. '</td> <td>' . $row['phone_number']. '</td> </td>';
        }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    } else {
        print " 0 results";
    }
}
?>
```

Update:

Your `$campDataSet->fetchAllCamps` returns an array of objects. This is more appropriate in this case:

```
<?php
    ...
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<td>' . $row->id_campsite. '</td> <td>' . $row->campsite_name . '</td> <td>' . $row->address . '</td> <td>' . $row->postcode . '</td> <td>' . $row->country. '</td> <td>' . $row->lattitude . '</td> <td>' . $row->longitude . '</td> <td>' . $row->email . '</td> <td>' . $row->phone_number . '</td> </td>';
    }
    ...
?>
```

Comment: i tried that and i got :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type campDataSet as array in F:\Client Server\Website\campsites.php:38 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: @DamianKlekot OK, if possible, post the output from `var_dump($result)`. Thanks.

Comment: Where do I place it or what do I change to add >var_dump ? Sorry quite new to php

Comment: @DamianKlekot Just `var_dump($result);` after `$result = $campDataSet->fetchAllCamps($sqlQuery);`.

Comment: too big to add to comments so i updated original post

Comment: i've messed around with it and now i get a different result from > var_dump($result) and this is the error i get when attempting to change the code into this :

`<?php
        ...
        foreach ($result as $object) {
            $row = $object->db;
            echo '<td>' . $row->username. '</td>';
        }
        ...
?>`

i now get an error saying
`Trying to get property 'id_campsites' of non-object`

if you check the updated of original post i've changed the outcome from `var_dump`

Comment: @DamianKlekot Now `$result` seems correct. Please, check updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `fetchAllCamps()` does the fetching for you, this is why you have an array rather than a result set, so instead of the line...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

replace it with

```
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
```